# how does matlibplotlib use a "reference" import?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I draw lines and rectangles using Matplotlib I usually use:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
Line2D(...)
```

But I also find somebody simply use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.Line2D(..)
```

I found `plt.Line2D` is in fact `<class 'matplotlib.lines.Line2D'>`, which means `matplotlib.pyplot.Line2D` is a reference to `matplotlib.lines.Line2D`?

I am curious in:

- How does it work? some python tricks?
- I would use `dir(plt)` to view but not in [The Pyplot API](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/pyplot_summary.html), should I know they are designed on purpose, or deprecated?

Comment: This isn't a `matplotlib` thing so much as a general Python thing. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `matplotlib.pyplot` there is a line saying

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
```

Hence, if you import `matplotlib.pyplot`, `Line2D` is available from the pyplot namespace,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.Line2D(...)
```

Because the availability in the namespace itself is not a documented feature, one should probably not rely on it. Also it is better style to use the functions/objects imported from their original submodule.
On the other hand it is very convenient to just write `plt.Rectangle` instead of having to import the patches module first.
I guess at the end you need to decide for yourself which case applies.